# Calculate annotated fields together

Tags: python, django

```
most_viewed_videos = Video.objects.filter(
                videowatch__created__month=today.month,
                viewing__status="D"
            ).annotate(
                count=Count("videowatch"),
                viewing_count=Sum("viewing")
            ).values("count", "viewing_count").order_by(
                "-viewing_count",
                "-count"
            )
```

Hey I have this code snippet and my question is how I can sum the `count` and `viewing_count` together to one result.

I tried around but I don't find anything what was working.

EDIT:
Solution what was working for me

> ```
>         most_viewed_videos = Video.objects.filter(
>             videowatch__created__month=today.month,
>             viewing__status="D"
>         ).extra(
>             select={'total': 'COUNT("videowatch") + SUM(CAST("viewing" as CHAR))'}
>         ).values("total").order_by("-total")
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can achieve it without using .extra(), here is the solution :

```
most_viewed_videos = Video.objects.filter(
            videowatch__created__month=today.month,
            viewing__status="D"
        ).annotate(
            count=Count("videowatch"),
            viewing_count=Sum("viewing"),
            count_viewing_count = Sum(F(Count("videowatch"))+F(Count("viewing")))
        ).values("count", "viewing_count").order_by(
            "-viewing_count",
            "-count"
        )
```

i didnt test that, but it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) queryset method to achieve that:

```
most_viewed_videos = Video.objects.filter(
        videowatch__created__month=today.month,
        viewing__status="D"
    ).annotate(
        count=Count("videowatch"),
        viewing_count=Sum("viewing")
    .extra(
        select={'total': 'COUNT(videowatch)+SUM(viewing)'}
    )
    ).values("count", "viewing_count").order_by(
        "-viewing_count",
        "-count"
)
```

I have not tested it though. I have faced similar issue "Annotation on previously annotated values". And seems like it is not possible, i have opened a [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19512) in the past but it was closed.